# How to use quosure-like syntax in base R formulas?

Tags: r, formula, tidyverse

I'd like to write a function like this:

```
library(survival)
getFit = function(x, data){
  survfit(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ x, data = data)
}
getFit(surgery, heart)
getFit("surgery", heart) #if not possible, this would be fine too
```

Of course, the `x` is not read. Please note that I use `survfit` with `heart` as an example but I encoutered this problem for nearly every formula based function (lm , glm etc).

I know I could write something with `paste` and `as.formula`, but I wondered if there was something like I'd do in a `tidyverse` way, something like:

```
getSurvPlot = function(x, data=db){
  xx = enquo(x)
  survfit(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ !!xx, data = data)
}
```

This last code doesn't work either, but I think this is because `survfit` is not part of the `tidyverse`.

Is there any clean way to write something like this in base R ?

**EDIT** : In this very example, I'd now be using `survminer::surv_fit`, which is a wrapper around `survfit` allowing more flexibility in formulas.

Comment: can you add your library call for `survfit` and `Surv` ?

Comment: where is the surgery data?

Comment: `surgery` is part of the `heart` dataset included in the `survival` library

Answer (score 2):

Here are 3 options, the 1st is pure base R and the 2 next ones use `rlang`.

**base R**

```
getFit1 = function(x, data){
  survfit(eval(substitute(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ x)), data = data)
}
```

**rlang**

There is no reason here to use `enquo` as it builds an object that contains the parent environment, in your example the object `surgery` doesn't exist in your global environment, it just needs to be evaluated in the context of the formula. So `substitute` is the appropriate function here as well.

to be able to use the `!!` argument we need a function that supports quasi quotated arguments, and then we need to evaluate it or convert it as formula (I don't know of a function that does both in one step).

So we end up with something that doesn't look better than the base version.

```
getFit2 = function(x, data){
  xx <- substitute(x)
  survfit(eval(expr(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ !!xx)), data = data)
}
```

**rlang again, using new_formula**

We can build a formula from its lhs and rhs, but now we need to quote the lhs and we still need `expr` on the rhs, so base solution still seems better suited for this case.

```
getFit3 = function(x, data){
  xx <- substitute(x)
  survfit(new_formula(quote(Surv(start, stop, event)), expr(!!xx)), data = data)
}
```

**output**

```
getFit1(surgery, heart)
# Call: survfit(formula = eval(substitute(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ 
#                                           x)), data = data)
# 
# records n.max n.start events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
# surgery=0     143    87       0     66     80      66     188
# surgery=1      29    16       0      9    980     186      NA

getFit2(surgery, heart)
# Call: survfit(formula = eval(expr(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ !!xx)), 
#               data = data)
# 
# records n.max n.start events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
# surgery=0     143    87       0     66     80      66     188
# surgery=1      29    16       0      9    980     186      NA

getFit3(surgery, heart)
# Call: survfit(formula = new_formula(quote(Surv(start, stop, event)), 
#                                     expr(!!xx)), data = data)
# 
# records n.max n.start events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
# surgery=0     143    87       0     66     80      66     188
# surgery=1      29    16       0      9    980     186      NA
```

Comment: This is a nice answer @Moody_Mudskipper. However, I want to highlight the importance of quosures, as `substitute()` does not play well with nested functions. If I define `fitHeart <- function(x) {getFit2(!!subsitute(x), heart)}` and call it as `fitHeart(surgery)`, it will fail. If I replace `substitute` with `ensym` in both `fitHeart()` and `getFit2()`, then everything will work as expected. (You want `ensym` instead of `enquo` because you're building up a formula and `enquo` will give you `~surgery` rather than `surgery`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Artem, I'm playing out of my league so I can learn here so I'm really happy that you set me straight.

Comment: @Artem, I can't find any function called `ensym`, did you give me the wrong name, or is it in the development version of `tidyeval` or `rlang` ? https://www.rdocumentation.org/search?q=ensym

Comment: Hmm... it's available in rlang 0.2.0 (https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/index.html), but I suppose that could still be the dev version.

Comment: nevermind, I think it's just an error by `RDocumentation`, my own version is old (and it's not straightforward to upgrade), so that led to confuse me further. It's in the cran doc as well.

Answer (score 2):

Moody_mudskipper gave a very nice detailed answer. I just wanted to note that your definition of `getSurvPlot` is almost correct. Your issue is not with rlang/tidyverse, but in using the quoted argument (which is a formula) inside another formula.

When calling `getSurvPlot(surgery, heart)`, `enquo` will capture the first argument as `~surgery`, which is already a formula. Rather than using `~` to create a new formula from `xx` and `Surv`, you only need to update the left-hand side of the formula you already have. This can be done using `stats::update()` from base R:

```
getSurvPlot <- function(x, data=db){
  xx <- enquo(x)
  survfit(stats::update( xx, Surv(start, stop, event) ~ . ), data = data)
}
```

`getSurvPlot(surgery, heart)` should now work as expected.

As pointed out by @Moody_mudskipper, the actual work is done by `stats::update.formula()`, which is an implementation of the [S3 generic](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html) `stats::update()` for formula objects, such as `xx`.

Comment: For doc one should look at `?stats::update.formula`, the default is designed for models which confused me for a few minutes :).

Comment: Thanks so much, @Moody_Mudskipper. I updated the answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

We can literally replace the RHS of the formula with the variable we need:

```
getFit = function(var, data){
  var=as.name(substitute(var))

  survfit(`[<-`(Surv(time, status)~. ,3,list(var)), data = data)
}

getFit(x,aml)
Call: survfit(formula = `[<-`(Surv(time, status) ~ ., 3, list(var)), 
    data = data)

                 n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
x=Maintained    11      7     31      18      NA
x=Nonmaintained 12     11     23       8      NA

getFit("x",aml)
Call: survfit(formula = `[<-`(Surv(time, status) ~ ., 3, list(var)), 
    data = data)

                 n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
x=Maintained    11      7     31      18      NA
x=Nonmaintained 12     11     23       8      NA
```

How do we know it is correct?

```
survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml) 
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml)

                 n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
x=Maintained    11      7     31      18      NA
x=Nonmaintained 12     11     23       8      NA
```

You can use:

```
getFit = function(var, data){
  var=as.name(substitute(var))
  a = `[<-`(Surv(time, status)~. ,3,list(var))
  survfit(a, data = data)
}
```

or

```
getFit = function(var, data){
  var=as.name(substitute(var))

  survfit(formula(substitute(Surv(time, status)~var,list(var=var))), data = data)
}
```

Comment: While this is a working answer, this is unfortunately not what I'd call "clean", unlike `tidyverse`. The survfit call is not really readable. Maybe this just cannot be done yet in base R.